# setSupportActionBar (androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar) in AppCompatActivity cannot be applied

Tags: android, android-appcompat, androidx

An error showing incompatible types Android widget toolbar cannot be converted in Java compiler while working on Android Studio.

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    toolbar.setTitle("GPS PRESENCE SYSTEM");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

> Error: incompatible types: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be converted
>   to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

Answer (score 38):

Try to replace this:

```
import android.widget.Toolbar;
```

With this:

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```

By the way, if you are using `androidx`. Run it's migration process.
The android support libraries will not be supported in the future.
You can read about it here:

[AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/)
[Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/)

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar); //No Problerm

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

> we must import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
>   don't import android.widget.Toolbar;

Answer (score 2):

This error because your Toolbar created using `android.widget.Toolbar` .
But you are using androidX. 
This also a same kind of error.
*java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to android.widget.Toolbar*

To solve this kind of you can add these to lines in to your MainActivity.java file (to import).

`import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;`

`import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;`

Make sure to remove or comment out this `android.widget.Toolbar` .
Then again check for error like this. because sometime you may have to import more.

Answer (score 1):

AndroidX is the new and improved support library

```
 import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```

you can check more about from here [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)

**Androidx's toolbar is designed for backwards compatibility while**

`android.widget.Toolbar`

**is the current plattform type**

Comment: Please, provide an explanation of your answer in order to make it clearer as possible, not only for the OP, but also for the community (In other words, insert what features that import should make available to solve OP's issues)

Comment: yes i have addedd full explanation but due to some problem only this was added PS:Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change your activity toolbar import to:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Comment: That's the old ToolBar not the new one. I'm not sure this advice is relevant past 2018.

Answer (score 0):

You are using androidx and Android both at the same time. That is throwing an error. Either use androidx or use android appcompat.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke [`ActivityCompat#requireViewById`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#requireViewById(android.app.Activity,%20int)) which allows to omit the type cast and returns a `@NonNull` `Toolbar` reference:

```
Toolbar toolbar = ActivityCompat.requireViewById(this, R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

The title can be set on the `@Nullable` `ActionBar` reference returned by [`AppCompatActivity#getSupportActionBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity#getSupportActionBar()):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setTitle("GPS PRESENCE SYSTEM");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply delete

```
import android.widget.Toolbar;
```

and add

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

As reported by everyone else

```
import android.widget.Toolbar
```

is creating the issue.

Replace it with

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

Mostly on android's recommendation we go for the tool and don't notice the android or androidx dependability.
That causes this error.