# How to reference androidx toolbar in main activity?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, androidx

I am trying to use my toolbar as my action bar but my reference to the toolbar is throwing an error. I am not using the previous `android.support.v7.widget` toolbar but the newer `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` toolbar. I believe there is a different syntax for androidx but could not find it.

```
package com.example.practice

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean this? > [android x action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56847882/setsupportactionbar-androidx-appcompat-widget-toolbar-in-appcompatactivity-can)

Comment: Could you post your xml for the main activity?  Your toolbar in xml should looks like <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar...

Comment: @OscarEmilioPerezMartinez

`<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />`

Comment: is your app theme's parent Theme.MaterialComponents.?

Comment: I was able to fix the issue. It was caused by mixing Java syntax with Kotlin. All i had to do was replace `Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)`  with `val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar`

Answer (score 0):

`Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);` is Java syntax; use

`val toolbar : Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar`

EDIT: Just noticed this was in a comment already, but it hasn't been answered yet anyway so :P